# Telegram - Number of visits of my channel banner returns to zero

Tags: telegram, banner-ads

when I send my banner to channels it earns visits that shown under banner. It should rise and calculate all visits other banners are like this, but when I send it to a new group or channel it returns to zero visit :. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when the post is deleted from the original channel that created it